# How to install MySQL on Android phone to use with node.js

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, shell, mobile

Are there any MySQL lightweight apps that can be installed on mobile android phone preferably in the background process?

I followed this tutorial [Building a Node.js application on Android](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-node-js-application-on-android-part-1-termux-vim-and-node-js-dfa90c28958f#.htce7wo5c) I'm able to run non-SQL node server scripts but I rely on MySQL instances to have a connection on localhost using node.js mysql module.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'database'
});
connection.connect();
```

Is there anyway I could create an MySQL instance on android actually?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/), because it uses a small file as it's database. It has a much smaller footprint than alternatives like mysql and postgres. Store it in the install directory of the node app and connect to it via a library like [knex.js](http://knexjs.org) or [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).

Example using knex.js (my preference):

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: "./mydb.sqlite"
  }
});
```